# I want to change values in Odoo

Tags: odoo

Here I want to change calculate the cost of merge and then calculate the sales price but result is wrong .. please help me

> list_price = Sales Price
> standard_price = cost
> mrg= marge
> cost=marge %
> list_price = standard_price*(1+mrg)

```py
from odoo import models, fields, api

class Marge_product_template(models.Model):
    _name = "product.template"
    _inherit = "product.template"
    mrg = fields.Integer(string="Marge")
    standard_price = fields.Float(string="Cost", store=True)

    @api.onchange("list_price", "standard_price", "mrg")
    def _onchange_cost(self):
        # set auto-changing field
        if self.mrg != 0:
            self.standard_price = (self.mrg * self.list_price) / 100

    @api.onchange("list_price", "standard_price", "mrg")
    def _onchange_vente(self):
        # set auto-changing field
        if self.standard_price != 0 and self.mrg != 0:
            self.list_price = self.standard_price * (1 + self.mrg)
```

[image: Result of code Is here In this capture]

Comment: I've reformatted your post and code to try and understand it better, but unfortunately I don't know the Odoo API well enough to help - sorry!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

This is speculation… I've been reading the tutorial and the [reference](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.api.onchange) but have never heard of Odoo before today. Quite *intrigued* by it, though!

The arguments for `@api.onchange` decorator mean "when these fields change, call this method", right?

If that's true, is it a mistake to have `"standard_price"` in the decorator when the function is to update `self.standard_price`?

```py
    @api.onchange("list_price", "standard_price", "mrg")
    #                           ^^^^ error? ^^^^
    def _onchange_cost(self):
        if self.mrg != 0:
            self.standard_price = (self.mrg * self.list_price) / 100
            # ^^ recursion? ^^
```

And by the same logic, `"list_price"` should not be in the `_onchange_vente` decorator.

Can you try this change and see if it works?

```py
    @api.onchange("list_price", "mrg") # removed "standard_price"
    def _onchange_cost(self):
        if self.mrg != 0:
            self.standard_price = (self.mrg * self.list_price) / 100

    @api.onchange("standard_price", "mrg") # removed "list_price"
    def _onchange_vente(self):
        if self.standard_price != 0 and self.mrg != 0:
            self.list_price = self.standard_price * (1 + self.mrg)
```

---

**Edit:** Further reading of the tutorial, [it has this to say](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/howtos/rdtraining/09_compute_onchange.html#how-to-use-them):

> In many cases, both computed fields and `onchanges` may be used to achieve the same result. Always prefer computed fields since they are also triggered outside of the context of a form view. Never ever use an `onchange` to add business logic to your model. This is a **very bad** idea since `onchanges` are not automatically triggered when creating a record programmatically; they are only triggered in the form view.

Therefore you might want to make `list_price` be computed using the `@api.depends` decorator, assuming this is business logic:

```py
class Marge_product_template(models.Model):
    _name = "product.template"
    _inherit = "product.template"
    mrg = fields.Integer(string="Marge")
    standard_price = fields.Float(string="Cost", store=True)
    list_price = fields.Float(string="List price", calculate=_onchange_vente)

    @api.depends("standard_price", "mrg")
    def _onchange_vente(self):
            self.list_price = self.standard_price * (1 + self.mrg)
```

Comment: It might also be the case that updating `standard_price` manually triggers `_onchange_vente` to recalculate `list_price` which triggers `_onchange_cost` to recalculate `standard_price` and it's this circular pattern which makes the problem. If you remove one of the `_onchange` functions does the other one work as expected?

Comment: Thanks all .. I solve the problem depends to the answers . the first problem is the parameter of @api.onchange . then th logic of calcul

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad! If this answer shows exactly how to solve the problem, please could you mark it as accepted? Otherwise, if it inspired you how to solve the problem in a different way, could you put in your own answer to show how? This benefits any future Odoo users who get stuck in a similar way.